# can you show me a proper syntax for using the ScheduleThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, swing

for this; i want the "Continuous" button to start rollthedice(), and the "Stop" button to stop it, but then when i hit the "Continuous" button again i want it to start rollthedice() again, back and forth

```
scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

ScheduledFuture now = null;

Runnable runner = new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
        rollthedice();
    }
};


if(e.getSource()==continuous)
{

    now = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 0, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
if(e.getSource()==stop)
{

    now.cancel(true);

}
```

Comment: have you tried a google search...

Comment: can you clarify what do you mean by "hit the continuous button"? Is it a user generate event? how do you do that?

Comment: its a JFrame GUI with the buttons "stop" and "continuous" this code is inside the actionPerformed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are missing is this Assignment to `ScheduledFuture` `now`

```
now = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runner, 0, 500,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Then you can call `now.cancel(true);`

Just move below declarations at class level i.e. you can move above your `actionPerformed` method. It works fine after that.

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
ScheduledFuture<?> now = null;
```

Comment: ok i did that and im getting a null pointer exception when i hit stop,and it doesnt stop rollthedice(), it says should be parameterized

Comment: there it is, im just a beginner trying to get into practice

Comment: thank you, first time using ScheduleThreadPoolExecutor i just downloaded the tutorial off oracle, it worked how you said, i just have to practice